# Make celery auto-reload on docker

Tags: python, docker, celery

Trying to add an auto reload to celery on a docker ,
as i need to develop and test task, changes in configuration
i'd like to have auto reload option without need to reload the docker each time.

following search i got to watchmedo but it doesn't work ,
still need to reload the docker on every change.

see compose file:

```yaml
worker:
  build:
    dockerfile: DockerfileCelery
    context: .
  command: watchmedo auto-restart --directory=./ --pattern=*.py --recursive -- celery worker --app=worker.celery --loglevel=info --logfile=logs/celery.log
  volumes:
     - ./multi/celery_app:/usr/src/app
  environment:
     - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redisjson:6379
     - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redisjson:6379
  depends_on:
    - redisjson
    - ws
```

would appreciate any help

##########################################
##########################################

Update :

still not working.

I run a virtual env (Ubuntu).

cellery.py

```
from decouple import AutoConfig

cwd = os.getcwd()
DOTENV_FILE = cwd + '/proj/config/.env'


config = AutoConfig(search_path='DOTENV_FILE')

app = Celery('proj',
             broker=config('CELERY_BROKER_URL'),
             backend=config('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'),
             include=['proj.tasks'])


app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

tasks.py

```
from .celery import app


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

spinning celery as :

```
watchmedo auto-restart --directory=proj/ -p '*.py' --recursive --  celery -A proj worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO
```

It's running and task being processed by worker.
But , if make change in tasks.py - no reload.
I need to restart celery.

Comment: Can you run this outside Docker?  Create a Python virtual environment, make sure the Redis container has `ports:` so it's accessible from outside the Compose setup, and set `CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://localhost:6379`; then you can have a host Celery worker reading tasks from a Docker queue.

Comment: @DavidMaze , Not sure i understand what u mean , how does it relate to redis? Celery workers lives in a docker as i need to have the option to deploy it in different host ....sorry not sure i get what u mean

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're ultimately deploying your application using Docker Compose, you're not forced to also use it for development, and you can use a more convenient environment for day-to-day development work.

Celery stores its jobs in a Redis instance.  If you're doing development work outside Docker, you need to make sure that Redis instance is accessible from the host.  Conversely, you do not need to replace the code or command of the standard worker (we won't be running it now).

```yaml
services:
  redisjson:
    image: redis
    ports:        # add if not present
      - 9999:6379 # you choose first number, second number must be 6379
  worker:
    # as in the question, but without volumes: or command:
```

Then you can start the dependent services, but not the worker itself

```sh
docker-compose up -d redisjson db
```

On your host system, create an ordinary Python virtual environment, if you don't already have one.  (There are various tools to manage these, I'm using the low-level tooling just as an example.)

```sh
cd multi/celery_app
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You also need to set the Celery-related environment variables to point at the published Redis using the `ports:` we added above.

```
# use the same number you chose for `ports:`
export CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://localhost:9999
export CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://localhost:9999
```

Now you should be able to run the worker directly, attach a debugger to it, work on the code in an IDE, use a live-reloading tool, and so on.

```sh
# on the host, but connecting to infrastructure in containers
celery worker --app=worker.celery --loglevel=info --logfile=logs/celery.log
```

Comment: I follow your suggestion ,Create a virtual env on ubuntu and install celery there - no change , main post updated with details.